# Napoleon/ Scipio

Tags: vocabulary, translation-check, names

Students of North & Hillard will be aware that Ex. 229 is a passage about Napoleon. In the answer book Ex. 229 is a passage concerning Scipio.

Does anyone know the refs for the Latin trans. of "Napoleon", and the English of "Scipio"?

Yes, I can do them myself; but, still like to see the correct versions - mine hardly ever are.

Comment: Could you try to rephrase this question so that it doesn't require having the book? One option would be just to put the sample sentences and translations here.

Answer (score 2):

Napoleon has the reputation (in my view, unfounded) of being the greatest general of all time (he did conquer almost the whole of Europe, as did Hitler, but both were defeated after a few years), and Scipio Africanus enjoys a similar (and perhaps better founded) reputation among the Romans. The explicit linking of the two is found in the book *A Greater than Napoleon: Scipio Africanus*,  London, 1926, by the famous English military historian Liddell Hart.

Comment: Liddell Hart (in fact not a general officer, but a captain) indeed makes a good and very readable comparison, but what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: @TomCotton. The cited exercise book implies that Scipio is to the ancient world as Napoleon is to the modern world. Thus, the one can be “translated” as the other. My answer drew attention to a (once) famous example of this analogy.

Comment: So this is not a mistake by the publishers of N&H?

Comment: @tony. I was referring to the book by Liddell Hart.

Comment: @fdb Instead using of the Latinized personal name (e.g. _Napoleonis_) that I would have expected, the N/H key has _Scipionis_. Certainly the implication that you propose is there, but it seems to me a rather strange, indeed bizarre and unnecessary substitution in such a manual! Anyway thank you:, you do us all a favour by reminding us of Liddell Hart's justly lauded opus.